Android webview with foreground service throws "Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView"
Hello Android experts,
I am working on an Angular-Capacitor Android app for a VOIP telephony solution.
After a recent update to my app where I bumped up the min sdk version to 29, I had to restructure my app to use foreground services. For example, without a microphone foreground service type, my app would release the microphone if it is minimised. So, it was necessary to use the foreground services.
However, that has started causing issues with the webview.
For example, when my app is in the background and I get an incoming call:

the app is woken up by a firebase messaging service
which starts a foreground service to use the Telecom Manager,
which shows the incoming call screen (which is a component in my angular application)
where the user can answer or decline.
if the user answers the call, all goes ok.
When disconnected, where I call activity.finish(), the activity is completed.

Now, if I open the app again and perform any action which has my native code send a message to angular through my custom capacitor plugin, I always get into the following error in the log:
Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView
    java.lang.Throwable
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.t(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-647818633:10)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.m(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-647818633:2)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.evaluateJavaScript(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-647818633:46)
        at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:894)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$eval$1(Bridge.java:832)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.$r8$lambda$c8L_lcj5D7mie6Lox_r5YdIsoIQ(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)

I understand that activity.finish() will kill the activity. That is why I expect that when the app is restarted (when the user clicks on the app icon in the launcher), it should start a fresh instance. I see my angular app loading into the webview. But somehow it keeps holding the last reference which has been destroyed.
The foreground service issue has been more evident for scenarios when the background service is still running and you close the app by swiping it off from the recent list. Even if the app is restarted after that, messages from native end using notifyListeners() fail to get through to the angular side. and it always ends up with the exception about Application attempted to call on a destroyed WebView.
I have tried several ways, but I am not able to fix this at all.
Is this a known issue? Any suggestions on how to fix this?
